# c# How can I call a void after another void?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have two voids that have to be called after one another every 5 seconds.I mean first the first void has to be called and after that the second void has to be called and the we have 5 seconds break...but my program only calls the first void(get pressure) and ignores the second one....could anyone show me the code?

```cs
private void getPressure()
{
    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        string PCR = "";
        byte[] readCommand = { 0x50, 0x0D };
        serialPort1.Write(readCommand, 0, 2);
        int bytestoread = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
        if (bytestoread > 0)
        {
            byte[] input = new byte[bytestoread];
            serialPort1.Read(input, 0, bytestoread);
            PCR = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(input);
        }
        if (PCR.StartsWith("P"))
        {
            if (PCR.Length > 15)
            {
                PCR = PCR.Substring(3, PCR.IndexOf("T") - 3).Trim();
                var decPCR = Decimal.Parse(PCR, NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
                rTxtBoxPressure.Text = decPCR + " Torr";
                double data;
                bool result = Double.TryParse(decPCR.ToString(), out data);
                if (result)
                {
                    serialDataChart.TriggeredUpdate(data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    
private void getVoltage()
{
    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        string UCR = "";
        byte[] readCommand2 = { 0x55, 0x0D };
        serialPort1.Write(readCommand2, 0, 2);
        int bytestoread2 = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
        if (bytestoread2 > 0)
        {
            byte[] input2 = new byte[bytestoread2];
            serialPort1.Read(input2, 0, bytestoread2);
            UCR = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(input2);
        }
        if (UCR.StartsWith("V"))
        {
            if (UCR.Length > 15)
            {
                UCR = UCR.Substring(5, UCR.IndexOf("Volts") - 5).Trim();
                var decUCR = Decimal.Parse(UCR, NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
                rtxtBoxVoltage.Text = decUCR + " Volts";
                double data;
                bool result = Double.TryParse(decUCR.ToString(), out data);
                if (result)
                {
                    serialDataChart2.TriggeredUpdate(data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    
private void InitTimer()
{
    timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval =5000;
    timer1.Start();
}
            
    
private void timer1_Tick(object sender , EventArgs e)
{
    getPressure();
    getVoltage();
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine. Although you consider the time every 5 seconds. It is possible that your first method will take a long time to execute. Debug your code to solve the problem

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh if it takes a long time to execute, what should I do?

Comment: How do you know the second method is ignored? Maybe there just isn't any data. Try to debug it.

Comment: @PalleDue  I used debugger and I have data.

Comment: OK. When debugging, you should probably stop your timer after the first tick, so it doesn't fire again and interrupt your debugging.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you define your time with `Interval = 5000`, which will trigger timer event every 5 seconds.

Secondly, in timer event handler you call desired methods one after another, without any interval, so once `getPressure` finishes, `getVoltage` starts immediately.

So, to sum it up - you don't need timer, as in your requirements I don't see that both functions should be called periodically. The only thing we need to call one, and then after 2 seconds call another, so I'd suggest something among the lines

```
getPressure();
// wait two seconds between calls, you could also use Thread.Sleep(2 * 1000)
await Task.Delay(2 * 1000);
getVoltage();
```

IF you want to wait 2 seconds before calling `getVoltage`, but it should be 2 seconds from starting `getPressure`, then the code should look like:

```
var pressureTask = Task.Run(() => getPressure());
await Task.Delay(2 * 1000);
getVoltage();

await pressureTask;
```

Comment: Keep in mind when using this answer that it's bad practice to assume getPressure() will be done after 2 seconds, doing whatever it does because you timed it once taking that amount of time on your dev machine.

Ideally, you will await the method being completed and once you have confirmation of completion, call the next one. If it's in your control, refactor getPressure into returning a bool or something else (I mean, it's a getter so I don't get why it's void in the first place) - and then once you have output, calling the getVoltage().

Comment: @Chrotenise you're right, but i just have given the options, it's up to OP what use-case is at hand, and what solution will be chosen. I covered cases you mention